Get driver to update after page click in selenium
I'm trying to build a simple webscraper. I want it to work by inputting a value into a webpage, clicking enter and then scraping the new page after the it loads.
So far initially loading up the webpage, inputting the value and clicking enter works but the driver does not seem to update when the new page loads, and as such I can scrape the new page for information.
Does anyone know how to get this functionality to work?
Code is below:
import selenium.webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

test_wage = float(53109.22)

options = selenium.webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.thesalarycalculator.co.uk/salary.php')

takehome_form = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "hero__input")
takehome_form.send_keys(test_wage)
takehome_form.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

The code above works fine, it is the following where I have issue:
result = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/section[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]")

Which produces the following error:
NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: /html/body/section[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception

Again, I think it is because the original webpage does not have this information, but the new webpage after clicking enter on the form and loading the new page does have this information, but the driver does not update and thinks the original webpage is open still.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Selenium will automatically wait for a click that navigates via a traditional full page load.  These days many sites will use Javascript to update the DOM instead of performing a full page load.  That's what webdriverwaits are designed for: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/

Two suggestions:

Utilize selenium's waits to effectively locate web elements
Use relative XPaths over absolute XPath as the latter are more brittle and more likely to throw NoSuchElementException when the HTML gets updated

Check the working code below:
import selenium.webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

test_wage = float(53109.22)

options = selenium.webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.thesalarycalculator.co.uk/salary.php')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

takehome_form = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "hero__input")))
takehome_form.send_keys(test_wage)
takehome_form.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

result = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//td[contains(@class,'takehome')])[2]")))
print(result.text)

Result:
£ 3,446.73

Process finished with exit code 0


This worked perfectly. Thank you so much <3

It might be because of the loading time of the web page. You should add this :
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "/html/body/section[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]"))
or just
WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
